# Need short URl for my Site htaccess

Tags: php, url-rewriting, short-url

I need to change

```
http://localhost/engineering/management/administrator/modules/course/view.php
```

to

```
http://localhost/engineering/course_view.php
```

I tried the following rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^engineering/([.*])_([.*])\.php$  /engineering/management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
```

But it does not affect the url. I think the code has some problem.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN Still its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.php$ management/administrator/modules/course/view.php
```

Since you are in localhost and inside the folder engineering, you can omit that in rule. This works only if you place the .htaccess inside the engineering folder.

http://localhost/engineering/course_view.php

Thanks,

Najeem

Answer (score 1):

Just delete '[' ']' from your rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/engineering/(.*)_(.*)\.php$  /engineering/management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
```

**UPD**
Added '/' at the beginnig of replace pattern.

P.S. Sorry, I can't check this rule myself. Haven't apache installed on my pc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , am removing that ,but still its not working

Comment: am placing the .htaccess file in the folder engineering

Comment: when am checking the url http://localhost/engineering/course_view.php "it shows 404 no page found error"

Comment: Thanks for your edit, But its not working ,this is my present htaccess file

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/engineering/(.*)_(.*)\.php$  /engineering/management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php

Comment: for cheking the effect am using the url: http://localhost/engineering/course_view.php

Comment: actual url : http://localhost/engineering/management/administrator/modules/course/view.php

Comment: Did you tried to place .htaccess to root directory of your site?

Comment: ...i replaced to root directory.. no chages..still "404 not found" error

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^engineering/(.*)_(.*)\.php$   engineering/management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php

Comment: But some problems my css and images for tht pages are not working